# How do I run South migrations (Django) on a database server?

Tags: python, mysql, database, django, django-south

Originally, I've just had servers that have both Django, South and my database installed (web + database server combined). But now, we're moving to a dedicate database server, and a dedicate web app server.

Since the database server doesn't have Django or South installed, how can I run migrations? Or at least, what's the best way to update the database with new schema changes? It's MySQL if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if the database is running on the same machine as django/South. Wherever your django installation lives has the database configured in its settings. South migrations should work exactly the same.